# Error reading Excel file using Spout

Tags: php, kohana-3.2

I am having trouble using the **spout** library in kohana 3.2 to import a big Excel file into mysql. These are the installation steps I have taken:

In the portal file index.php, I added this line of code:

```
require_once APPPATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'kohana'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Spout'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."Autoloader/autoload.php";
```

This is my `reader` method:

```
public static function reader($filename){

    $result = array();

    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
    $reader->open($filename);


    while ($reader->hasNextRow()) {
        $row = $reader->nextRow();
        $code = $row[1];
        $result[] = $code;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

When I try calling the method, this error message appears:

```
ERROR: ErrorException [ 1 ]: Class 'ReaderFactory' not found ~ APPPATH/classes/kohana/spoutexcel.php [ 70 ]
2015-09-25 14:29:10 --- STRACE: ErrorException [ 1 ]: Class 'ReaderFactory' not found ~ APPPATH/classes/kohana/spoutexcel.php [ 70 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Spout can be found here: https://github.com/box/spout

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It could be that the Spout autoloader is looking for its classes in the wrong directory. I assume that the spout classes should be in the `APPPATH/classes/kohana/Spout`directory, and not in its parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Spout? If you used Composer, you'll need to include (`require_once`) the `autoload.php` file generated by composer when you installed Spout.

If you did not use Composer, you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/box/spout#manual-installation. It explains which file you need to include to autoload Spout classes.

And as @mrBrown mentioned, don't forget to define the namespaces, by using `use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the namespace?

`use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;`